# How to track traffic data from widget implementation on 3rd Party page within Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I want to track traffic and referals in the following multi domain setup:

There are three pages (and domains):

1. Traffic Page (e.g. Google)
2. Brand Page (e.g. Apple.com iPhone Page)
3. Shop Product Page (e.g. Amazon iPhone Page)

On the Brand Page there is a widget implemented, which is hosted by my server and a "buy now" button:

```
<a href="#" class="btn" sku="89389468" id="buybutton">Bestellen</a>
<src="myserver.io/buywidget.js">
```

Once the customer clicks on the buy now button a widget will open where he can pick a shoping destination.

What would be a recommended approach with Google Analytics so I can track:

1. Views of brand page (where my widget is implemented)
2. Clicks on the button on brand page
3. Clicks on the shoping destination link on brand page
4. Traffic Source to brand page (if possible)

Is this even possible? I am open to any other suggestion on how to track the funnel.